# GPT/GAM - how can I get dynamic key-values to appear in reports?

Tags: google-ad-manager, google-publisher-tag

I am setting targeting key-values via `googletag`. The final goal is to have such key-values in GAM reports.

This works with predefined key-values but it doesn't seem to work with dynamic key-values

On GAM I defined 2 keys:

- a predefined one called `a_predefined_key`
- a dynamic one called `a_dynamic_key`

[key-values list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny5De.png)

Client side I am setting both:

```
window.googletag.pubads().setTargeting('a_predefined_key', 'predefined_value_2');
window.googletag.pubads().setTargeting('a_dynamic_key', 'dynamic_value_1');
```

The 2 values appear in the `cust_params`:

```
https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?...&cust_params=a_predefined_key%3Dpredefined_value_2%26a_dynamic_key%3Ddynamic_value_1...
```

The report settings look like this:

[Report settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvARr.png)

The result of the report only shows the predefined key:

[report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ0n1.png)

How do I get the dynamic key-values to appear in the report too?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It does work the same way for dynamix and predefined values on my account. was your report time period including the date when you created your dynamic key ?

Comment: Hi @rabsom, thanks for the answer! The key-values were created few minutes apart, in the same day. So the report date range should include both of them